# REST API design with existing API for object creation

Tags: api, rest

I'm quite unsure, whats the best way to redesign our api, because we may made some mistakes in the previous one...

We have an endpoint for an object lets call it a Thing

```
/api/{version}/thing
```

there is an existing POST with a DTO object that contains an id property of a user and a deprecated number property of a user along with thing properties to define to whom it belongs and what it is. Now we need that number property although its deprecated to use either userid OR number to identify the user

```
ThingDTO {
  @deprecated
  val number = ""
  val userid = ""
  val name = ""
}

POST /api/{version}/thing/ ThingDTO
```

the number or id always identifies the user who creates the thing, but I think it was a mistake to put it into the DTO?
The number value is not stored to the thing, there is only the reference to the actual user, so its just used for identification

Which option would you recommend to change the api to?

New ThingDTO

```
ThingDTOv2 {
  val name = ""
}
```

1. 

create two new routes for user and number and passing the concrete value along with a parameter to create the thing

```
POST /api/{apiVersion}/thing/user?userId=userid ThingDTOv2
POST /api/{apiVersion}/thing/number?number=number ThingDTOv2
```

2. 

call a parameter identifier and pass either number or userid and check if a user can be found for one of these values by id or number

```
POST /api/{apiVersion}/thing/?identifier=userid|number ThingDTOv2
```

3. 

this option is not possible anymore, because this route without parameters already exist with ThingDTOv1

```
POST /api/{apiVersion}/thing/?userId=userid&number=number ThingDTOv2
```

4. 

use the existing API and "undeprecate" the number property. Then decide on the server if any user can be found either for userid or number. if two different are found -> Exception, if one user is found -> use this, if same user is found for both values -> its fine

```
ThingDTO {
  val number = ""
  val userid = ""
  val name = ""
}

POST /api/{version}/thing/ ThingDTO
```

kind regards

Comment: Damn sorry but thats an ugly design.

Comment: i know, but the existing api is what it is, the question is how can we design the new one better?